# Show that if $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ and $g\circ h$ is a no constant polynomial then $g$ and $h$ are polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let two entire functions(holomorphic in all $\mathbb{C}$) $g$ and $h$ so that the composition $g\circ h$  is a no constant polynomial. Show that $g$ and $h$ are polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is not a polynomial, we know that $g$ takes a value say $c$ an infinity of time, ie there exists an infinite sequence $z_n$ of distinct points such that $g(z_n)=c$. As $h$ is entire, we know that at most one value of the sequence $z_n$ is not in the range of $h$, ie we can find a sequence $y_n$ of different points such that $h(y_n)=z_n$ for all but one index. So we can find an infinite sequence of distinct points $y_n$ such that $g\circ h (y_n)=c$, and $g\circ h$ is not a polynomial.

So $g$ is a polynomial.

It is even simpler to prove that $h$ is a polynomial : if not there exists a infinite sequence of distinct complex numbers $z_n$ such that $h(y_n)= c$, then $g\circ h (z_n)=c$ and this function is not a polynomial.

Comment: why $g$ takes a value  $c$ an infinity of time?

Comment: I think this is called the big Picard Theorem. You can also use the so called Weirstrass-Casaroti theoremto check that there exists such a $c$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem